# Error trying to create a new table in SQL

Tags: sql, string, oracle11g, create-table

I am doing some SQL exercises and one of them requires me to run the given code that creates a new table

```
CREATE TABLE TDEPTO_1 (
    NUMDE INTEGER,
    NUMCE INTEGER,
    DIREC INTEGER,
    TIDIR TEXT,
    PRESU INT,
    DEPDE INT,
    NOMDE TEXT,
    CONSTRAINT [PK] PRIMARY KEY ([NUMDE])
);
```

But when I try to run it in Oracle Aplication Express, it displays this error message

> ORA-00902: invalid datatype

Comment: Did you get this `CREATE TABLE` statement from SQL Server?

Comment: It could be, I got it from my college teacher

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TEXT` datatype does not exist in Oracle. You want to use `VARCHAR2(n)`, where `n` is the maximum number of bytes that your column can allow (maximum 4000 bytes).

Depending on your Oracle version, `INT` and `INTEGER` may work, but it is better to use `PLS_INTEGER`

Also, you should remove the brackets (`[]`) in the definition of the constraint, as this will also generate an error in Oracle.

Try (change the `100` to the desired text length) :

```
CREATE TABLE TDEPTO_1 (
    NUMDE PLS_INTEGER,
    NUMCE PLS_INTEGER,
    DIREC PLS_INTEGER,
    TIDIR VARCHAR2(100),
    PRESU PLS_INTEGER,
    DEPDE PLS_INTEGER,
    NOMDE VARCHAR2(100),
    CONSTRAINT PK PRIMARY KEY (NUMDE)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your current code appears to be SQL Server.  In Oracle, there is no data type exactly called `INTEGER`, but there is a `PLS_INTEGER`.  Similarly, there is no `TEXT` type, but we can use something like `VARCHAR2`:

```
CREATE TABLE TDEPTO_1 (
    NUMDE PLS_INTEGER,
    NUMCE PLS_INTEGER,
    DIREC PLS_INTEGER,
    TIDIR VARCHAR2(100),
    PRESU PLS_INTEGER,
    DEPDE PLS_INTEGER,
    NOMDE VARCHAR2(100),
    CONSTRAINT PK PRIMARY KEY (NUMDE)
);
```